# French/English word database for a hangman game

Tags: data-request, education, english, french

I'm currently developing a Hangman game in English for a French website that teaches English. I'm looking for a database containing a set of English words, preferably common nouns or verbs of more than 5 letters, and ideally their French translation. TIA

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site :). Would it be possible to add any more details to your question - take a read of [What makes a good data-request?](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look) It's just to your question is more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I'd suggest using the flashcards from an [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) deck.

Here's a list of French decks: https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/french

You can convert the deck to txt/csv with these steps: https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1589071665

Once you have the txt/csv file, you can easily either manually or with a simple script prune the list to meet your need (e.g. 5 letters or more).

([License & Terms](https://ankiweb.net/account/terms) of using Anki decks)

---

Another option is one of the many online lists "N most commonly used French words". Here's a [generic search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=1000%20most%20common%20french%20words%20english%20translation&t=h_&ia=web) to get you started.